# Django how update page after receiving POST request?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new with Django.

I would like to update the page in the browser each time a POST request is received by the app. By the moment, I send POST request with POSTMAN. At the end, it is another webserver which will send data through POST request.

I don't find any solution to do this.

This the code in my view :

```
@csrf_exempt
def prem(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("GET")
        context = {'contenu': request.GET.get("request_received", "nothing") }
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print("POST")
        datar = request.GET.get('request_received','rien')
        context = { 'request_received' : datar }

    return render(request, 'polls/seco.html', context)
```

Code in my template :

```
{% if request_received %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Message received from POST request : {{ request_received }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Someone could help me ?

Comment: what kind of webserver are you talking about?

Comment: I have a webserver on which one I save data from sensor. Once this data is caught by the webserver, it does a POST request to send it to Django. Finally, what I want is to display this data on my browser and update it instantly when the sensor catch a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have written (in the comments ), it seems you want the webpage to dynamically update in real time (without reloading) whenever a request is received.

This is technicaly not possible as django does not maintain connection with client once the response has been sent.

You will have to save the incoming post request(from POSTMAN) to db.

Then in the templete , you can either use AJAX to continuously check whether a new request has arrived or make use of websockets to retain connection with user.

Websockets are faster than AJAX. Thus they are what you want as you wrote 'instantly' in comments. AJAX request can take a few seconds in the worst case.

In django , you can use django-channels for websockets

[django channels](https://github.com/django/channels)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer ! You have helped me